# how to preserve this div in the bottom of the site?

Tags: css

I have a big problem in my website (based on Joomla and a free template).
When I go to this page: **http://bit.ly/2mv4pC**
I should set the margin of *{ p.stickynote }* to *{ margin-bottom:300px; }* in order to fix the problem of my .

If you just try to play with the *{ margin-bottom:300px; }*, so you will see the behavior of this , deleting this margin will make this div appear in the center of my page.

I've added those properties *{bottom:0px;}{position:fixed;}* to *{ div style="bottom: 0px;" id="footer-cover" }* but the background "Black banner in the bottom" still the same.

Is there any suggestion to make it fixed in the bottom of the site?

Comment: Seems the asker of the question edited it and removed the question. Do we roll back? or close?

Comment: Since there are answers I rolled back the edit so that the question is actually showing.

Comment: Interesting way to delete the question....but why multiple lines of 123 and not just "removed"?

Comment: There are still parts that aren't showing. "...fix the problem of my ." and such.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just inserting some line code but the formating mechanism prevented me to put { *<div style="bottom: 0px;" id="footer-cover">* }

Comment: @Proxium: You can put HTML code in by using the back-ticks, or by putting it on its own line and indenting by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that without the margin on the bottom, the page height is shorter then the window bounds, thus your footer div ends and the body of the page bleeds through.

What's the intended effect you want to achieve? Do you want the footer to overlay content and always be visible? Or do you want the footer to just always be at the bottom of the page?

For the first:

```
#footer-cover {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  bottom: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

For the second:

- You want a sticky footer technique, similar to [this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) (Thanks for the better link ZJR), I can't remember all the details of it but has to do with setting a negative margin. It's a little hackey but it works alright.

---

Hopefully this is close to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: for the second requesto also the http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ is a good example/showcase

Comment: [ryanfait.com](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) was a great site even if I've found that [cssstickyfooter.com](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com) was a better alternative. I applied the first one and now my site [bit.ly/2mv4pC](http://bit.ly/2mv4pC) does not suffer more from this strange footer :) Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you got it working. 
ZJR: Thanks for the link, was a quick google for me so I wanted to get at least some sticky technique out there. I'll edit the answer to include your link as well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I quite understand your question, but I'll give it a guess anyway.
I think you want your "black banner" to be on the bottom of the browser viewer not the page itself, like the chat-bar-thingy on facebook.

So to do that you do this:

```
<style>
  #header{}
  #content{margin-bottom:100px} /*to make room for the footer*/
  #footer{height:100px; position:fixed; bottom:0}
</style>

<div id="header" />
<div id="content" />
<div id="footer" />
```